# Input validation displays error message that should only show up in an if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am putting together a WordPress theme options page. I am trying to figure out if a url entered into a text field passes a validation. If it doesn't, I want to display a message at the top of the admin page to correct what is entered.

In this case, I want to display **File type must have the file extension .jpg, .jpeg, .gif or .png** at the top of the page when a user enters a file with any other extension. This message is within an if statement, but it is showing up regardless of what is typed into the field. I would like to know what mistake I am making here or if the input is even being validated.

Here is the code within the initialization of the options page

```
add_action('admin_init', 'theme_admin_init');

function theme_admin_init() {
    register_setting(
        'coolorange_theme_options',
        'coolorange_options',
        'coolorange_options_validate'
    );
    // what each parameter represents:
    // add_settings_field($id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args);
    add_settings_section(
        'coolorange_logo_main',
        'Logo Section Settings',
        'logo_section_text',
        'coolorange'
    );
    add_settings_field(
        'upload_image_button',
        '<strong>Upload logo to the Media Folder</strong>',
        'file_upload_button',
        'coolorange',
        'coolorange_logo_main'
    ); // Upload Logo button
    add_settings_field(
        'logo_textfields',
        '<strong>Logo location</strong>',
        'file_location',
        'coolorange',
        'coolorange_logo_main'
    ); // logo url, width and height text fields
    add_settings_field(
        'restore_selectbox',
        '<strong>Restore original heading</strong>',
        'restore_dropdown',
        'coolorange',
        'coolorange_logo_main'
    );
}
```

Here is the code for the input box (this is within a file_location() function):

```
<strong>File URL:</strong> <input id="image_url" type="text" value="<?php $options['image_url']; ?>" size="60" name="coolorange_options[image_url]" />
```

And this is the validation code:

```
//Validation
function coolorange_options_validate($input) {
    $options = get_option('coolorange_theme_options');
    //check filetypes for image url
    $options['image_url'] = trim($input['image_url']);
    if ( !preg_match ( '/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/', $options['image_url'] ) ) { //opens if statement
        $options['image_url'] = ''; 
        echo '<div id="message" style="color: red;"><p>File type must have the file extension .jpg, .jpeg, .gif or .png</p></div>';
    } // closes if statement
    else {

    }
    return $options;
}

add_action('admin_notices', 'coolorange_options_validate'); 
//shows validation errors at the top of the page
```

Comment: What is a sample output of `$options['image_url']`? Also, does the `else` statement get executed?

Comment: As I am new to php, I'm not sure how to answer this question, but a sample output would be a url with file extension only of .jpg, .gif or .png. So far as the else statement goes, I was trying to get the function to do nothing and leave the input as is. But, the else statement is probably irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem is in the `html` name in following line

```
<strong>File URL:</strong> <input id="image_url" type="text" value="<?php $options['image_url']; ?>" size="60" name="coolorange_options[image_url]" />
```

It should be like following

```
<strong>File URL:</strong> <input id="image_url" type="text" value="<?php $options['image_url']; ?>" size="60" name="coolorange_theme_options[image_url]" />
```

As you are expecting `$options = get_option('coolorange_theme_options');`.

Comment: I tried changing the register_setting function so that the group and name of options are the same like this: `register_setting('coolorange_theme_options', 'coolorange_theme_options', 'coolorange_options_validate');` and changed the name under each input to `coolorange_theme_options[name_of_input]`, but the problem still persists. This message is showing up at the top of every page in the admin panel.

Comment: Can you please check what `$options` contain in function `coolorange_options_validate`? Use `var_dump($options);`. I am guessing `$options['image_url']` is always `null` and that is why you are getting the message all time.

Comment: I typed in var_dump($options) at the top of the function. The output that shows is `array(4) { ["image_url"]=> string(0) "" ["image_width"]=> string(5) "728px" ["image_height"]=> string(5) "120px" ["select_options"]=> string(7) "default" }`. Where do I go from here to fix this?

Comment: So looks like from `html` `image_url` is sending empty string. So every time you are getting the message. Please make sure from view page (`html`) you are getting correct value.

Comment: After typing the url into the image_url input and clicking Save Changes, the code shows: `<style type="text/css"><!-- #logo { background: url('http://apache.localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/jgs_wordpress_themes_logo012.png') top center no-repeat; ...rest of stylesheet`. But the var_dump($options) still shows an empty string for image_url.